# Evaluate integral with high power under square root

Tags: integration

How to solve this case? If only it had been $x^2$ instead of $x^4$, I would set $x=sinht$ ...

$$ \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^{4}}}dx  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set
$$
u=x^2,\ u=\sinh t,
$$
then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}\,dx&=&\frac12\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\,du=\frac12\int\frac{\cosh t}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2t}}\,dt\\
&=&\frac12\int\,dt=\frac12t+c=\frac12\sinh^{-1}(x^2)+c
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:** $x^4+1 = (x^2)^2 + 1$.

**Hint 2:** *Hover mouse over the grey box below*

> Substitute $x^2 = \sinh t$. Everything simplifies nicely.

Comment: Congrats on joining the 10k club!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach may be to set $1+x^4=t^2x^4$ according to https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Differential_binomial.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^2=\sinh \theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} d x & =\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\cosh \theta d \theta}{\cosh \theta} \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \theta+C \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \sinh ^{-1}\left(x^2\right)+C .
\end{aligned}
$$